# UNION two SELECT queries but result set is smaller than one of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

In a SQL Server statement there is

```
SELECT id, book, acnt, prod, category from Table1 <where clause...>
UNION
SELECT id, book, acnt, prod, category from Table2 <where clause...>
```

The first query returned **131,972** lines of data; the 2nd one, **147,692** lines. I didn't notice there is any commonly shared line of data from these two tables, so I expect the result set after UNION should be the same as the sum of 131972 + 147692 = 279,384.

However the result set after UNION is **133,857**. Even though they might have overlapped lines that I accidently missed, the result should be at least the same as the larger result set of those two. I can't figure how the number 133,857 came from.

Is my understanding about SQL UNION correct? I use SQL server in this case.

Comment: `UNION` de-duplicates your data, so if a row appears multiple times its only shown once. You want `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand comment given under the question, which I think states what you already know:

`UNION` takes care of duplicates also within one table as well.

Just take a look at a example:

SETUP:

```
create table tbl1 (col1 int, col2 int);
insert into tbl1 values
(1,2),
(3,4);
create table tbl2 (col1 int, col2 int);
insert into tbl1 values
(1,2),
(1,2),
(1,2),
(3,4);
```

Query

```
select * from tbl1
union 
select * from tbl2;
```

will produce output

```
col1 | col2
-----|------
1    | 2
3    | 4
```

[DB fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/844cd/1)